# Gauge freedom in general relativity for non-vanishing energy momentum tensor

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, gauge-invariance

When studying the linearized Einstein field equations in vaccum

$$\partial^{\lambda}\partial_{\nu}\gamma_{\lambda\mu} + \partial^{\lambda}\partial_{\mu}\gamma_{\lambda\nu} - \eta_{\mu\nu}\partial^{\lambda}\partial^{\sigma}\gamma_{\lambda\sigma} - \Box \gamma_{\mu\nu}= 0, \tag{1}$$

with the metric pertubation $h_{\mu\nu} = \gamma_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}\eta_{\mu\nu}\gamma_{\;\lambda}^{\lambda}$, one has the freedom to choose a gauge, since the equations themselves do not determine any specific coordinate system and physics is invariant under a change of coordinates. It is then common to choose (among other conditions) $\partial_{\nu}\gamma^{\mu\nu}=0$ such that the field equations simplify to

$$\Box \gamma_{\mu\nu}= 0. \tag{2}$$

This procedure as it is done when investigating gravitational waves is clear to me. However I struggle to understand the notion of gauge freedom when the energy momentum tensor does not vanish. In this case the field equations are given by

$$\partial^{\lambda}\partial_{\nu}\gamma_{\lambda\mu} + \partial^{\lambda}\partial_{\mu}\gamma_{\lambda\nu} - \eta_{\mu\nu}\partial^{\lambda}\partial^{\sigma}\gamma_{\lambda\sigma} - \Box \gamma_{\mu\nu}= \frac{16\pi G}{c^4}T_{\mu\nu}. \tag{3}$$

In my lecture notes the same gauge transformation as above is applied which gives

$$\Box \gamma_{\mu\nu} = -\frac{16\pi G}{c^4}T_{\mu\nu}. \tag{4}$$

My problem is the following: Let $\gamma_{\mu\nu}$ be a solution to equation 3 then it has an implicit dependence on the values of $T_{\mu\nu}$ and hence also the coordinate transformation I have to perform to ensure $\partial_{\nu}\gamma^{\mu\nu}=0$ depends on it. But under the coordinate transformation of course also the components of $T_{\mu\nu}$ transform. Since fixing a gauge comes down to fixing a specific coordinate system I would have to know the components of $T_{\mu\nu}$ in these new coordinates in order to solve equation 4, which is hard since the procedure does not give an explicit form for these new coordinates. In my lecture notes they just plug in the energy momentum tensor for dust $T_{\mu\nu} = \rho u_{\mu}u_{\nu}$ in an arbitrary coordinate system with $u_\mu = \delta_\mu^0$, where it is not obvious to me why I can do that.

In other words it seems to me as if the choice of source term $T_{\mu\nu}$, at least locally, already specifies a specific coordinate system (in contrast to the situation in vacuum) which would destroy the freedom to choose any gauge we like.

I would appreciate an explanation where my error in reasoning is.